# Creating a column to keep count

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 4 columns  ID, animalid ,  calvdate  and AnimalidLactNo i want to add  an extra column called lactationNo that does a count when the date of an animalid changes i would give it a count number

The following is my table

```
CREATE TABLE `calvingdatecombined` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `animalid` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `calvDate` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=65536 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

My expected output :

```
#ID, animalid,calvDate,LactationID

1,ANIM400,2015-10-14,1
2,ANIM400,2015-10-15,2
3,ANIM400,2016-10-14,3
4,ANIM403,2015-10-14,1
5,ANIM404,2015-10-14,1
```

Comment: which version of Mysql you are using

Comment: my MySql version is 5.7.23

Comment: Search for mysql row number simulation.

Comment: Is it possible to have duplicate values for animalid and calvdate ? Meaning  can two or more rows exists having same animalid and calvdate value ?

Comment: yes it is possible to duplicate animalid and calvdate: animalid can occur several times for as long as calvdate keeps changing

Comment: Then, will they have same LactationID ?

Comment: the lactationid should be different for the same animalid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL version < 8.0, we can [emulate Row number functionality](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/) using Session variables:

```
SELECT 
  dt.ID, 
  @row_num := IF(@aid <> dt.animalid, 1, @row_num + 1) AS LactationID, 
  @aid := dt.animalid AS animalid, 
  dt.calvDate 
FROM 
(
  SELECT
    ID, 
    animalid, 
    calvDate
  FROM calvingdatecombined 
  ORDER BY animalid, calvDate, ID
) AS dt 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_num := 0, 
                   @aid := '') AS user_init_vars 
ORDER BY dt.ID
```

Comment: is it possible to put this query under a view so that i do not have to write this query over and over again @madhur Bhaiya

Comment: @MirieriMogaka Should be possible. Haven't tried earlier though. Give it a try. Let me know if it throws some error or something.

Comment: it throws an error contains a variable or parameter @madhur bhaiya

Comment: @MirieriMogaka hmm.. looks not possible then. If you can upgrade to latest MySQL version (8.0.2 +), you can directly use window functions like `Row_number()`

Comment: can i create a custom function which i can use in place of Row_number()

Comment: @MirieriMogaka it will not be efficient, as it will be computing for every row, without an inherent optimizations done by MySQL (eg: indexing)